# How to get debug output from Testcontainers during unit tests in .net

Tags: .net, .net-7.0, testcontainers

When something goes wrong creating the container the test results and exception thrown give no clue to what the actual problem is. I am looking for a way to get output similar to what you get when manually starting a docker container.

From some posts I discovered I should be configuring a logger but I do not get any output.

The way I configured the logger is

```cs
        var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug)
                   .AddConsole();
        });
        TestcontainersSettings.Logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HaproxyDataplaneFixture>();
```

I do this before I create the containers. It is building fine but I do not see any additional output. Not in the output > tests nor in output > debug. I also tried running `dotnet test` in a commandline window and it also only showed the normal test output without any additional logging.

My test framework is xUnit in case it matters.